# There are multiple definitions of a variable but the linker does not generate errors on my machine

Tags: c, linker-errors

In my current project I'm initializing a window to draw on. I'm using a function pointer to deal with initialization from multiple platforms. So I really only want one instance of the window_init function pointer.

I noticed that I had forgotten to mark this function pointer as extern in my header file and defined it a second time in my C file to give it storage.

The header is included in multiple files so should, to my understanding, generate a linker error. I tested this on my laptop and it did in fact generate a linker error. Why is my desktop not generating errors/how can I find out? In both instances I used mingw64 with cmake in Clion to build, using `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`.

So for clarity: my desktop builds fine, my laptop gives me linker errors. I expect linker errors for both machines and I want to find out why that doesn't happen.

The solution is of course to use extern and then it builds on both machines, however I want to know what is going on.

Here is a minimal example which also builds fine on my desktop while I'd expect it to fail:

**window.h**

```
#ifndef CEXTERNTETS_WINDOW_H
#define CEXTERNTETS_WINDOW_H

void window_functions_init();

void(*window_init)(); //This is the first definition and should be marked as extern to my understanding if I want to give it storage in my c file

#endif //CEXTERNTETS_WINDOW_H
```

**window.c**

```
#include "window.h"
#include <stdio.h>


void(*window_init)(); //This is the second definition

void window_init_implementation()
{
    printf("window_init_implementation\n");
}


void window_functions_init()
{
    window_init = &window_functions_init;
}
```

**second include** (I need to include window.h in multiple files so I added it here and added a function so that the compiler can't optimize it away)

```
#ifndef CEXTERNTETS_SECOND_INCLUDE_H
#define CEXTERNTETS_SECOND_INCLUDE_H

#include "window.h"

void doit()
{
    printf("doit");
}

#endif //CEXTERNTETS_SECOND_INCLUDE_H
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "window.h"
#include "second_include.h"

int main() {
    window_functions_init();
    window_init();
    doit();

    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

edit:

Was able to find [this](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armclang_ref/armclang_ref_chr1422532346348.htm) about -fno-common.

Comment: This is a common compiler extension popular in the Unix world. To disable the extension, use `-fno-common`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. If I google -fno-common I get nothing, where can I find documentation for this?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I'm actually compiling with -pedantic. Shouldn't this disable the extensions? I'm fiddling around with -pedantic-errors -ansi -pedantic but the error doesn't show up until I use -fno-common.

Comment: There are two issues:  (1) What happens when the same declaration is repeated in a single source file, and (2) What happens when it is repeated in multiple source files that are linked together.  The `-fno-common` option pertains to the second case, but not the first.

Comment: @TomKarzes how does -fno-common relate to -pedantic though? I'd expect that the pedantic option disables all extensions, resulting in an ansi, standard compliant compilation.

Comment: Apparently the `-pedantic` option does not complain about the same declaration in multiple source files.

Comment: @TomKarzes that much is clear. It scares me a bit though, what other mistakes/noncompliant code am I writing that gets passed anyway by a non-disabled extension... Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is non-compliant.  I agree that it is undesirable, but many C compilers have supported this since the very early days of C.  I'm not sure if ANSI C explicitly addresses this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common compiler extension popular in the Unix world. To disable the extension, use `-fno-common`.

`-fno-common` is not enabled in GCC before version 10 by default with any warning or standard option. This technically does not constitute a violation of the standard, because the standard list this as undefined behaviour. Undefined behaviour does not generally require diagnostic messages. An implementation is allowed to define behaviour that the standard leaves undefined.

This is however undesirable, and GCC 10 finally [defaults to `-fno-common`](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-10/porting_to.html).